# Getting the text between two spans with "Simple HTML DOM"

Tags: php, dom, text, html

Basically, I need to get the text between two span tags, and I've tried a bunch of different methods with no solution.
I'm using Simple HTML DOM Parser (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) too, so what I can do is a little restricted to.
Here is the basic setup:

```
<span class=1>text here</span> TEXT I NEED TO GET <span class=2>more text</span>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text between the span elements should be a DOMTextNode and sibling to the span elements. If SimpleHTMLDom follows [DOM specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html) you should be able to get it with:

```
$text = $html->find('span[class=1]', 0)->next_sibling();
```

If that doesnt work, consider using a more proper parser that is based on libxml, e.g. see

- [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: That returns the 2nd span. Guess I'll have to rewrite my code for a new parser.

Answer (score 1):

## find('text', $index)

> This will give you blocks of text.

Try this:

```
echo $html->find('text',1);
```

output:

```
TEXT I NEED TO GET
```

## [DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/9zwr-hwit)

Answer (score 0):

Try [PHP Dom](http://php.net/manual/class.domdocument.php):

```
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHtml('
    <span class=1>text here</span> TEXT I NEED TO GET <span class=2>more text</span>
');

$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//body/text()') as $textNode) {
    echo $textNode->nodeValue; // will be: ' TEXT I NEED TO GET '
}
```

Comment: You might want to add some explanation to that because the XPath is non-obvious when you dont know what loadHTML does to HTML fragments.

Comment: @Gordon You're probably right, but it seems this topic is closed. ;)