# Get text from within tags that have other children

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing

I have html file in this [Statsoft site](http://www.statsoft.com//textbook/statistics-glossary/z/?button=0#Z%20Distribution%20%28Standard%20Normal%29), specifically in this part:

```
<p>
    <a name="Z Distribution (Standard Normal)">
        <font color="#000080" size="4">
            Z Distribution (Standard Normal). 
        </font>
    </a>
    The Z distribution (or standard normal distribution) function is determined by the following formula:
</p>
```

I want the text `The Z distribution (or standard normal distribution) function is determined by the following formula:` and I wrote some codes like this:

```
include('simple_html_dom2.php');
$url = 'http://www.statsoft.com//textbook/statistics-glossary/z/?button=0#Z Distribution (Standard Normal)';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($curl_scraped_page);

foreach ($html->find('/p/a [size="4"]') as $e) {
    echo $e->innertext . '<br>';
}
```

It just gave me: `Z Distribution (Standard Normal).`

I've tried writing

```
foreach ( $html->find('/p/a [size="4"]/font') as $e ) {
```

but it gave me a blank page.

What have I missed? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the paragraph, then remove the text from the link:

```
include('simple_html_dom2.php');
$url = 'http://www.statsoft.com//textbook/statistics-glossary/z/?button=0#Z Distribution (Standard Normal)';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($curl_scraped_page);

foreach ( $html->find('/p/a [size="4"]') as $font ) {
    $link = $font->parent();
    $paragraph = $link->parent();

    $text = str_replace($link->plaintext, '', $paragraph->plaintext);

    echo $text;
}
```

---

Original answer:

Your question is related to this one: [Getting the text between two spans with "Simple HTML DOM"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911378/getting-the-text-between-two-spans-with-simple-html-dom)

Your selector is finding the `font` tag, its parent (`a` tag) is a sibling of the text you want:

```
$text = $html->find('/p/a', 0)->next_sibling();
```

Comment: Find `/p`, inside that element, find `a` and remove the text from `a`

Comment: Will you please put that code into my code? I think I don't get how to put your solution into my problem.. Thank you.